# "Do you know why did he make that decision ?" vs. "Do you know why he made that decision ?"

Tags: questions

Is there any connotation difference between these two questions :

> "Do you know why did he make that decision ?"

and :

> "Do you know why he made that decision ?"

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Do you know why he made that decision?"** is a correctly built question.

"Why he made that decision" is the object of the sentence (do you know *(what?)* why he made that decision?)

It's not right to try to build 2 questions within 1 sentence.

Making the object of the sentence, use the affirmative sentence word order:

> Do you know why *he did that*?
>
> Do you understand why *I am doing this*?
>
> Do you realize how hard *I have been trying*?

Comment: So the first question is not grammatically incorrect, is it ?

Comment: @Enguroo Yes it is! (Grammatically ***incorrect***.) The first sentence is not grammatical. Either *did* or *do you know* has to be removed.

Comment: @Norbert the first sentence is grammatically incorrect.